# Combine each two pages to single from pdf book

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have such a pdf opened by Okular with Facing pages view mode (center first page).

[image]

I want to get all the two-pages view pictures, so manually crop them one by one.

How could extract them to pictures with combining two pages as single one?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pdfjam` from the `texlive-extra-utils` to combine pages horizontally or vertically in one page.

Also the tool `montage` from Imagemagicks (installed by default) can do that.

For simple cases, just printing to a PDF may do the job. In the Print dialog of your application, select "Print to file". On the "Page setup" tab, you can indicate that multiple pages must be printed on a single page.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pdfjam` from `texlive-core` to do this:

```
pdfjam --landscape --nup '2x1' --outfile output.pdf -- doc.pdf -;
```